# How make a cluster of CoreOS on my local infrastructure?

Tags: cluster-computing, docker, coreos, proxmox

I have some professional servers, and I want to create a cluster of 7-15  machines with [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/). I'm a little familiar with [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com), but I'm not clear about how create a virtual machine(VM) with CoreOS on proxmox. Also, I'm not sure if the idea of cluster of CoreOS's VM on proxmox it's right to do.

Then, I need:

1. How create a VM with CoreOS on proxmox.
2. If will be viable proxmox to create CoreOS's cluster.

Comment: I would ask this question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: ok, @NielsBom but I don't know how move it. I was created the question here because proxmox and docker tags was created here but coreos was not at that time...only some week ago appear coreos tag on stackoverflow.com

Comment: No problem :-) @kikicarbonell you can vote to move your own question to serverfault, here's how: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site

Comment: @NielsBom I not found a link to vote for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Proxmox, but if you can make an image that runs then you can use it to stamp out the cluster. What you'd need to do is boot the ISO, run the installer and then make an image of that. Be sure to delete /etc/machine-id before you create the image.

CoreOS uses cloud-config to connect the machines together and configure a few parameters related to networking -- basically anything to get the machines talking to the cluster. A cloud-config file should be provided as a config-drive image, which is basically like mounting a CD-ROM to the VM. You'll have to check the docs on Proxmox to see if it supports that. More info here: http://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-config-drive/

The other option you have is to skip the VMs altogether and instead of using Proxmox, just boot CoreOS directly on your hardware. You can do this by booting the ISO and installing or doing something like iPXE: http://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/booting-with-ipxe/

Comment: then how do you create a cluster if you skip the VMs? The problem is not the booting, its connecting to the machines without a way to SSH into the VMs with the keys.